# How to read data from .sh file in vba

Tags: vba

I am working on project VBA that required get data from .sh file.
I already try to read by the same way as text file (.txt) and binary file (.bin) but can not get data. 
Please help me find a way to read data from files with SH extension.

This is what I already try:

1. Open fileName For Input
2. Open fileName For Binary Lock Read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple Text file reading Algo will work:**

```
Sub ReadFileLineByLine()

    Dim my_file As Integer
    Dim text_line As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim i As Integer

    file_name = "C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\update.sh" 'change path of Sh File

    my_file = FreeFile()
    Open file_name For Input As my_file

    i = 1

    While Not EOF(my_file)
        Line Input #my_file, text_line
        'Cells(i, "A").Value = text_line
        Debug.Print text_line
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

***Courtesy:*** [Read a Text File](https://excel.officetuts.net/en/vba/read-a-text-file)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly !! My mistake is reading the whole file instead read line by line.